# What .gitignore should I use for PHP in Github?

Tags: github, version-control

Github.com and Github Desktop both asked the format of .gitignore I wanna use when creating a new repo. But PHP is not in the selection.

So which should I select?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then try one of the PHP gitignore proposed by [gitignore.io](http://gitignore.io)

It mainly depends on the editor you are using.
For instance: [`phpstorm+all`](http://gitignore.io/api/phpstorm+all).

In the OP's case, for [Wordpress](http://gitignore.io/api/wordpress):

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/wordpress
# Edit at https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=wordpress
### WordPress ###
# ignore everything in the root except the "wp-content" directory.
!wp-content/

# ignore everything in the "wp-content" directory, except:
# "mu-plugins", "plugins", "themes" directory
wp-content/*
!wp-content/mu-plugins/
!wp-content/plugins/
!wp-content/themes/

# ignore these plugins
wp-content/plugins/hello.php

# ignore specific themes
wp-content/themes/twenty*/

# ignore node dependency directories
node_modules/

# ignore log files and databases
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/wordpress
```

Comment: I'm using pure PHP, I'm actually developing on WordPress, building plugins/themes. There's no option for pure PHP.

Comment: @hivolih247 No, but there is one for Wordpress. See my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, found it. So, can I just assume that i just need to copy the content of https://www.gitignore.io/api/wordpress and save the file as .gitignore and save it under my Wordpress root folder and commit it to Git?

Comment: @hivolih247 That is the idea, yes. Do a `git status` to make sure what you want ignored is ignored. It some were already tracked/versioned, you can untrack them with a `git rm --cached`

Answer (score 0):

You can get current gitignore from [pull request](https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/3258)